# Unable to install PDFMiner

Tags: python, windows, 7zip, pdfminer

I am trying to install the PDFMiner library, and after downloading the tar.gz file from

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/
```

Afterwards, it says to run the setup.py file, but after extracting the files using 7ZIP, for some weird reason there is no setup.py file. I have attached an image of how the extracted folder looks like.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Extract the contents of the tar file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install PDFMiner, follow these step-

1. Install python 2.4 or newer. (Python 3.x is not supported.)
2. Download the PDFMiner source.
3. Unpack it. (ie. extract the archive)
4. Run setup.py to install: `python setup.py install`

That's it!

Comment: I did the exact same thing as you mentioned, but after extracting, I get the files as attached above. Is that  how is it supposed to look after extracting?

Comment: @The Bolt extract the tar file!

Comment: @sayan i extracted the tar file but i'm still not able to set this up

Comment: Same here, I can't open the setup.py from terminal command python setup.py install. I am wondering it is because my pdfminer folder directory is the wrong place.